# Ionic Native File append: true throwing error "Not Found" if the file is not there

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am trying `File.writefile` from Ionic Native and I'm having issues with the weather parameter.

Here's the link to the docs - https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/

```
File.writeFile('file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/', 'result.txt', `testing123\n`, {append: true}).then(succ=>{
      alert("File write success : " + JSON.stringify(succ))
    },
    err=>{
      alert(" write File error : " + JSON.stringify(err))
});
```

When I use `{replace: true}` it will write a new file every time but not append the data.

If I use `{append: true}` then it won't create a file on the file run...it has to exist.

How do I get it to create a file if it doesn't exists and append to it?

Comment: I'm using ionic 6 with Ionic native file plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around, trap the error, create the file and recall your function.

Also use `await` as it increases readability.

```
await File.writeFile('file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/', 'result.txt', `testing123\n`, {append: true}).catch (e) {
     await File.writeFile('file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/', 'result.txt', `testing123\n`, {append: false});
}
```

Comment: Typescript is saying: Cannot find name 'e' ... any ideas?